# Estimating the wind speed above the mojave desert

Tags: numerical-analysis

What equation would you all use to estimate the wind speed over the Mojave Desert in December? I'd like to model the speed of the wind up to say 50 thousand feet.

I read up about wind speeds on Wikipedia and they give an analytical formula for wind gradient:

$$\\ v_w(h) = v_{10} \cdot \left(  \frac {h} {h_{10}} \right)^ a$$

I also found this link:
http://digital-desert.com/mojave-preserve/geology/02.html
But it doesn't tell me how to vary altitude.

I would rather be using data that was taken, for example by NOAA, but couldn't find any. Does anybody have a link, algorithm, or recommendation of what I should do?

Comment: Here's NOAA's global wind data: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.ncep.html This is a blend of modeled and observed data. It's not very high resolution (after all, it covers the whole globe) and I doubt you'll be able to find anything that is.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ . I would re-post there, but try to give a more specific question (e.g. outline what you intend to use the data for)

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! As posed, this question is a bit outside of our scope, since it appears to be more about earth science and less about computational methods for solving a scientific problem. Please let me know if you would like me to migrate it to Earth Science Stack Exchange; if so, please undertake some of the edits suggested by GeoMatt22.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not describe a problem in computational science.